# Is there a C# function that checks if a list is empty and doesn't count null as an element?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am trying to use .Any() to validate if a list of elements is empty but there is a possibility it contains null elements and returns true, which I don't want.  Is there a way to validate a list is empty, ignoring nulls?

```
return salesList.Any() ? salesList : null;
```

The null values I sometimes have in the list prevent this from ever returning null.

Comment: use `.Where()` before `.Any()` to filter all `null` values

Comment: Do you want to remove the `null` items as well?

Comment: Not really, but that would also fix it. What did you have in mind @RufusL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
return salesList.Any(item => item != null) ? salesList : null;
```

This overload of `Enumerable.Any` will only count the items that will match the predicate. In this case all non-`null` items.

Comment: @Jalex don't forget to mark this as the answer to toss a couple extra Rep Sefe's way